# How can I turn my java class into a executable program that takes in parameters?

Tags: java, asp-classic, applet, zpl, javaexe

I have a java class that currently takes in a string of ZPL and sends it to a zebra printer. My goal is to connect an asp page with this java class. I was hoping that I could turn my java class into an executable and use a WshShell object on my asp page to execute the java class and pass it a string parameter that is supplied on the asp page itself. I have been looking into java applets to see if I could accomplish this task as well, but I am worried that the applet won't be able to access my Zebra Printer through a Tcp/Ip socket connection due to the fact that applets are ran in a "sandbox" mode. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you execute the jar on the server (ASP) then it's not an applet. How do you use/call your class today? If it really would be running as applet, the you can specify  `Permissions: all-permissions` to overcome the sandbox restrictions.

Comment: *"..worried that the applet won't be able to.."* See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).